# Why aren't my allocated memory blocks consistent?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to write a memory allocator in c++ for a class and for some reason my allocated blocks are not holding their data correctly when the program attempts to free them.

Basically there's a vector of lists that hold memory blocks of different sizes. When a portion of memory is requested, a suitable block is found and returned to the user. If a proper block is not found in one of the lists, but there's one that's larger, the larger block is removed from the list, split in half and those two blocks are inserted in the level below.

The program can also free memory blocks by inserting them back into the list and looking for its "buddy" (the block other block that was made when its parent was split) to try and merge them, which it does recursively as long as it can. It does this by checking the memory address of the block.

For some reason between the allocation and the free calls my memory blocks are being altered and Im not sure why.

alloc():

```
`void *BuddyAllocator::alloc(int length)
{
  cout << "Block size " << length << " requested" << endl;
  int rounded_length = round_up(length);
  if (rounded_length <= available_mem)
  {
    cout << "Searching for block size " << rounded_length << endl;
    bool loop = true;
    while (loop)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i <= FreeList.size(); i++)
      {
        if (FreeList[i].head != nullptr)
        {
          BlockHeader *iter = FreeList[i].head;
          if (iter->block_size == rounded_length && iter->free)
          {
            cout << "Suitable block found, returning block "<<iter<<" size: " << iter->block_size << endl;
            loop = false;
            FreeList[i].remove(iter);
            available_mem -= iter->block_size;
            return (void *)iter;
          }
          else if (iter->block_size > rounded_length && iter->free)
          {
            cout << "Large block found, splitting block size: " << iter->block_size << endl;
            split(iter);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Not enough memory available" << endl;
  }
  return nullptr;
}`
```

```
split: `void *BuddyAllocator::split(BlockHeader *block)
{
  int level = log2((double)block->block_size / basic_block_size);
  BlockHeader *left = block;
  int child_size = block->block_size / 2;
  left->block_size = child_size;
  BlockHeader *right = new ((char *)block + left->block_size) BlockHeader(child_size, true);
  FreeList[level].remove(block);
  FreeList[level - 1].insert(right);
  cout << "inserting right block into level: " << level - 1 << " size: " << child_size << endl;
  FreeList[level - 1].insert(left);
  cout << "inserting left block into level: " << level - 1 << " size: " << child_size << endl;
}`
```

free():

```
`void BuddyAllocator::free(void *a)
{
  BlockHeader *to_free = (BlockHeader *)a;
  int level = log2((double)to_free->block_size / basic_block_size); //find level to insert block into
  FreeList[level].insert(to_free);
  BlockHeader *iter = to_free->next;
  cout << "Freeing memory: " << to_free << endl
       << "Block size: " << to_free->block_size << endl;

  while (1 == 1)
  {
    if (((char *)iter == ((char *)to_free + to_free->block_size))) //check addresses to check for match
    {
      cout << "Joining segments" << endl;
      BlockHeader *joined_block = new ((char *)to_free) BlockHeader(to_free->block_size * 2, true);
      joined_block->next = nullptr;
      FreeList[level].remove(iter);
      FreeList[level].remove(to_free);
      free(joined_block);
      break;
    }
    else if ((char *)iter == ((char *)to_free - to_free->block_size)) //check addresses to check for match
    {
      cout << "Joining segments" << endl;
      BlockHeader *joined_block = new ((char *)iter) BlockHeader(to_free->block_size * 2, true);
      joined_block->next = nullptr;
      FreeList[level].remove(iter);
      FreeList[level].remove(to_free);
      free(joined_block);
      break;
    }
    else if (iter != nullptr)
    {
      iter = iter->next;
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "Buddy not found :(" << endl;
      break;
    }
  }
}`
```

This is the error that I'm having:
[image]

You can see that when block 0x7...a410 is allocated it correctly shows that the block is size 1024, but when I try to free the same address it shows size 111138594 (really wrong). It doesn't always happen, as you can see when block 0x7...a210 shows size 128 both when it's allocated and when its freed.

My code looks right and with simple tests (allocate one, free the same one and thats it) it works, but I cant figure out why it doesnt work when I try to automatically allocated/free the blocks. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Allocators don’t usually return the data structure node (BlockHeader in your case). They return the blank area within it as `void *`. If your callers store data in the return value of the allocator, they will overwrite its fields.

Simple “allocate, then free” would work. The problem is if you use the allocator’s return.

Similarly, on free, you need to find the BlockHeader from the `void *` within it. Usually you do this by subtracting the field offset or `sizeof(BlockHeader)`